# How to get the output in mysql the way i need is give below

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

i have one table with a single column having three values a,b and c.
Current snapshot of the table is

Table name:- tblTest

Values

```
tblColumn
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
```

i need to get the output exactly as

```
A B C
3 4 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN colName = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A,
        SUM(CASE WHEN colName = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as B,
        SUM(CASE WHEN colName = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as C
FROM tableName
```

another technique is by using `PreparedStatement`, this is very good if you have multiple unknown number group of values, eg, `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,...`

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(tblColumn = ''',
      tblColumn,
      ''', 1, 0)) AS ',
      tblColumn 
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM Table1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58ce2/7)

Comment: Note the values are lowercase. When comparing "case insensitive" the results will be the same either way. But when comparing "case sensitive" you have to use lowercase values too.

Comment: @MihaiStancu yep, anyway i just added prepared statement.

Comment: [here's another example: adding another records which doesn't need to modify the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a703f/1)

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(tblColumn = 'a') as A,
    sum(tblColumn = 'b') as B,
    sum(tblColumn = 'b') as C
from tblTest
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a831fa/3)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select tblColumn, Count(*) from tblTest group by tblColumn
```

Comment: The result set won't be structured as requested.

Comment: Agree, RedFilter... we can do without Distinct().. :) Changed.